# Finatra downloads HTML file instead of displaying it

Tags: scala, finatra

I am using Finatra 2.1.6 with this code:

```
get("/:*") { request: Request =>
response.ok.fileOrIndex(
  request.params("*"),
  "index.html")
}
```

If I run this from e.g. IntelliJ, it works perfectly fine and displays the html file. However, if I start the server from an assembled jar (using `sbt assembly`), it does not: Whenever I try to access index.html, which I put in `src/resources/index.html`, it tries to download the file since the contentType is set to `application/octet-stream` instead of e.g., `text/html`.

How can I change the behaviour so it renders the html file (or css, js,...) rather than downloading it?

Answer (score 3):

Finally could solve the problem. My merge strategy for `sbt assembly` would be something like

```
val meta = """META.INF(.)*""".r
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  ...
  case meta(_) => MergeStrategy.discard
  ...
}
```

which would discard the file `mime.types` which denotes what MIME type to use for a given file extension. I changed this to

```
val metaMime = """META.INF(.)mime.types""".r
val meta = """META.INF(.)*""".r
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  ...
  case metaMime(_) => MergeStrategy.deduplicate
  case meta(_) => MergeStrategy.discard
  ...
}
```

and now it works perfectly fine.